# GPU Driver issue with Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I an new to Android Development and Android Studio, and I am trying to run the emulator, but unfortunately, everytime I run it I get the following error.

```
GPU #1
Make: 8086
Model: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
Device ID: 0a16

Some Users have experienced emulator stability issues with this driver version.
As a result, we're selecting a compatibility renderer. Please check with your manufacturer to see if there is an
updated driver available.
```

Does anyone know how to fix it,

My computer's details:

Processor: Intel Core i3-4005 CPU @ 1.70 GHz

Graphics: Intel HD Graphics Family

Model: Dell Inspiron 3542

RAM: 4GB

Hard Disk 1TB

Answer (score -1):

I encounter this warning on my hackintosh (Lenovo X230, Intel HD 4000).
I tried to force hardware use with no success.

Did you try this one emulator from Microsoft?
https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/

In my case, on my Windows machine (same X230), the emulator keeps stalling on the profiles screen...

I have an old macbook pro with HD3000 on which the emulator runs fine, though the graphic chip is part of from Intel's HD family.

Comment: I am in the process of installing an Emultor called Genymotion.

it is an Emulator inside a virtal box. When I finish installing it, see how it functions, and I will post something here

Comment: I tried Genymotion an Android Emulator, and yes the emulator keeps stalling on the on the home screen (it stays black for a very long time).

Maybe my problem is that my laptop doesn't have enough processing power, or a powerful GPU for Android Virtual Device, or any Android Emulator